Flutter - The package project's method is not available on the app project
I want to separate my project's code between the application and the package, so making it available in the future to be installed on multiple projects. I want to develop for both at the same time, not publishing the package first like in most tutorials.
After flutter create --template=package myflutter, I just copied all the code from the app project to the package one first, and removed certain parts from both. Let say I have two directories within lib respectively views and modules, I remove the modules from app and keep them in the package.
So on the app side, I just added a dependencies into pubspec.yaml making it
dependencies:
  myflutter:
    path: package_path

On the package, I created the lib/myflutter.dart file containing all the exports of the dart files for all classes those I need them available.
library myflutter;

export 'dir/file.dart';
...

So from the app file, I can just put import 'package:myflutter/myflutter.dart'; into all files that need to import the package plugin.
I thought once I add an export, it will all be immediately available for the app code, but it's not. No guarantee for that. Sometimes it is, most of the time it's not. Quick Fix always show the suggestion to the long indirect path even I had already include the export to it, which is not what I want.
But even after I built both projects, the method still not resolved, showing the InvalidType error.
The question is what did I missed? I'll add a simplified version of my code to be added into the question in case if it's not clear. Thanks.
